# Remove specific lines in .txt resulting from from 'Dir /s' Windows Command

Tags: regex, editpad

Comparing files on multiple thumbdrive to delete duplicate and older files.
Tools:  Directory listings created using Microsoft command.com: dir /s >> directory.txt
Remove all blank lines, lines that begin with date (format: mm/dd/yyyy) time (format: hh:mm AM|PM)  . and lines that begin with date (format: mm/dd/yyyy) time (format: hh:mm AM|PM)  .. using Editpad Lite regular expression function.
With 'find'function, I can find blank lines with the expression: ^$
Want to use 'replace' function to delete the blank lines using regular expression.  Manually, I can press the 'delete' key but too tedious.

What is the regular expression to find lines that begin with date (format: mm/dd/yyyy) time (format: hh:mm AM|PM)  . and lines that begin with date (format: mm/dd/yyyy) time (format: hh:mm AM|PM)  .. 
What is the regular expression in the replace to delete these lines.

Thanks in advance.
Not sure which is better to use (Notepad++ or Editpad lite) to use regular expression.

'find'function, the regular expression finds the blank line: ^$
'replace function, the regular expression to delete line (failed): no entry or \$

'find'function, the regular expression finds [0-9]*/[0-9]*/[0-9]* finds the date (format: mm/dd/yyyy) string.

'find'function, the regular expression finds [0-9]*:[0-9]* [a-zA-Z] failed to find the time (format: hh:mm AM|PM) string.

See 2 for attempted code

The string searching for is deleted.
Error message ... red X

Comment: try command `findstr -v`

Comment: Why not just use `dir /s /b`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ With reference to the sentence "_See 2 for attempted code_ " in your post; should this be a link to something?

Comment: To Dudi Boy:  Thanks ... will look into it

Comment: To Andrei Odgov:  Thanks ... will keep the command handy

Comment: To inputforcolor:  No link,  "See 2 for attempted code" meant to reference section 2 of Stackoverflow input form for the regular expression code I tried.